# MongoDB: Añadir array de valores en array

Tags: mongodb

Me estoy volviendo loco para hacer algo tan simple como insertar un nuevo valor (un array de 2 valores) dentro de un array de la colección informes:

Intento hacer esto pero nada:

```
db.informes.update(
    {nombre:"Informe de Proyectos"},
    {$push:{propiedadesProyecto:
      {$each:[codigoPropiedad: "warningButton",
              titulo:"Warning Button"]
      }
    }
})
```

Debería de quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has intentado `{ $push: { propiedadesProyecto: {codigoPropiedad: "warningButton", titulo:"Warning Button"}}}`?

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, mil gracias!!!

Comment: Tu pregunta se titula: *Añadir array de valores en array* y el comentario te propone *añadir un objeto en array* y dices que funciona. ¿Por lo cual supongo que el título está mal? Una cosa es hacer `push` de un objeto, otra hacer `push` de cada uno de los valores de una lista. ¿Cuál de las 2 es?